# How to achieve two adjacent divs, one fixed-width and one responsive

Tags: html, responsive-design, width

Using the HTML below, I want the first `div` to have a static width of `265px`. The second `div` should be next to the first one, but should be responsive (by shrinking the window this `div` should also shrink). How can I achieve this?

```html
<div class="styles container">
    <h1>Styles</h1>
</div>
<div class="preview container">
    <h1>Preview</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your CSS. It will be helpful to show what you've tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`width: calc()` will not work in all browsers.
[Look at browser-support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

```
<div style="width: 265px; float: left; background: #00f;">
    test
</div>
<div style="width: calc(100%-265px); background: #000;">
    test
</div>
```